# Mongoose - How would I go about limiting the size of a pushed array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using NodeJS and Mongoose to write some endpoints. The following code is currently working as intended. It returns an array of results from my database where each result is made up of and ID and an array of values which looks like the following:

```
**[ { _id: 'Kitchen', values: [ 60, 60, 60, 60, 54 ] },
  { _id: 'My Desk', values: [ 40, 40 ] },
  { _id: 'Server Room', values: [ 50, 50, 50 ] } ]**
```

I am currently trying to figure out how to limit the size of the pushed array to a max of the 30 newest records. I believe I need to use splice in some way but I can quite get that to work. Here is the code I am currently using:

```
    router.get("/api/getsensordata/", function (req, res) {
  let sensorNames = req.query.sensornames.split(",");
  let device = SensorData.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { sensorName: { $in: sensorNames } },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$sensorName",
        values: {
          $push: "$sensorValue",
        },
      },
    },
  ])
    .sort({ _id: "ascending" })
    .exec(function (err, results) {
      if (err) {
        res.send("an error has occured");
      } else {
        console.log(results);
        res.json(results);
      }
    });
});
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can go about achieving this?

Comment: Use the $slice modifier.

Comment: @D.SM I was trying that modifier but how do I properly apply it to the $push?

Comment: The manual provides examples.

Answer (score 0):

[$slice operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) has to be applied after the grouping.

```js
let device = SensorData.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { sensorName: { $in: sensorNames } },
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$sensorName",
        values: {
          $push: "$sensorValue",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $project: { values: {$slice: ["$values", 30]}}
    }
  ])
```

Given the [RAM limits on group operator for large datasets](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-operator-and-memory), I recommend [limiting](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) the number of documents that are grouped.
You should [order the documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/#sort-aggregation) before limiting the documents that are grouped.

```js
 let device = SensorData.aggregate([
    {
      $match: { sensorName: { $in: sensorNames } },
    },
    {
      $limit: 30
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$sensorName",
        values: {
          $push: "$sensorValue",
        },
      },
    }
  ])
```